# In iOS, is it possible open a url in safari, then go back to the app and reopen safari without pushing a new url?

Tags: ios, swift, safari

I have a simple app that opens a link in Safari with UIApplication.shared.open. The user might navigate to any number of urls in the site, and then hit the Back arrow in the top left corner as return to the app.  Is it possible to launch Safari again, but without a new url, and simply open the tab at the same url location where navigation stopped, prior to pressing the back button?  The only way I know to open Safari is to push a url it, which means a user cannot resume using a site in Safari where they left off.  I would appreciate any ideas on how to implement this feature.

Comment: Don't exit to Safari; use `SFSafariViewController`.

Comment: That would be my preference, however I'm receiving push notifications that include a url.  When the notification is clicked, I would like to open the url in the browser, but the SFSafariViewController won't let me push urls to it once open.  I would use WKWebView, but it doesn't have Sharing, and a number of other Safari features.